# Big Query Slot estimator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Currently, GCP Projects use BigQuery with "On Demand" pricing and I search to know how many slots I should purchased if I switch to "flat rate" pricing.
I have top folder with projects inside and I search query which can provide slot usage for this folder, to purchase right number of slot.

I try something like this but i don't understand how I can targeted specific folder and if this query will works fine

```
SELECT
SUM(total_slot_ms) / (1000*60*60*24*7) AS avg_slots
FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_FOLDER
WHERE
 -- Filter by the partition column first to limit the amount of data scanned. Eight days
 -- allows for jobs created before the 7 day end_time filter.
 creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
 AND job_type = "QUERY"
 AND end_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

I can retrieve folder number to target it but it is an array
[image: request with select *]

Comment: I updated my answer. Did my anser help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the slots with this formula:

```
Number of slot = total_slot_ms / TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time,start_time, MILLISECOND)
```

You can use this example query:

```
   select job_id ,total_slot_ms / TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time,start_time,MILLISECOND) as num_slot from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
```

You can filter by `project_id`, `project_number`, `job_id` or `referenced_tables`.

or manually using BQ UI execution details if you don't have access to the table above:

```
Number of slot = Slot time consumed (convert in MILLISECOND)/Elapses time (convert in MILLISECOND)
```

Another option is to use BigQuery monitoring with the System Tables Reports Dashboard to check how many slots your account is using.

You can see more [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/monitoring-bigquery-reservations-and-slot-utilization-information_schema) about monitoring and BigQuery.

To extract the folder_name from the array, you need to use the [SAFE_OFFSET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_subscript_operator) function. You can see this example with OFFSET.

```
WITH items AS
 (SELECT ["apples", "bananas", "pears", "grapes"] as list union all
 SELECT ["watermelon", "peach", "orange", "avocado"]
 )
 SELECT
 list[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as safe_offset_0,
 list[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] as safe_offset_1,
 list[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] as safe_offset_2,
 list[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] as safe_offset_3
FROM items;
```

This is the output.

[image]

In your case could be something like this:

```
SELECT folder_numbers[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as id,folder_numbers[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] as folder_number,
SUM(total_slot_ms) / (1000*60*60*24*7) AS avg_slots
FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_FOLDER
WHERE...........
GROUP BY  total_slot_ms,folder_numbers[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have not many skills in SQL and I don't understand how to build the right request with targeted folder, "folder_number" is an array in bigquery

Comment: @Thomas AUBUGEAU I udpated my answer

Comment: thanks, but I have a problem : SELECT
folder_numbers[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] as folder_number,
 SUM(total_slot_ms) / (1000*60*60*24*7) AS avg_slots
FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION  .........................                                                   ERROR : SELECT list expression references column folder_numbers which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:1]

Comment: @Thomas AUBUGEAU In your query you have a stament GROUP BY you need to add this field folder_numbers[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]